# Containers vs Serverless vs Virtual Machines

Tags: containers, virtual-machine, serverless

I made some research about Containers, Serverless, and Virtual machines all of these has its own benefits like cost, deployments, reliability, etc. but I am still confused when to use these, and what kind of situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Virtual Machines (Hypervisor)

This straightforwardly emulates an OS, the virtualization is given a predefined amount of resources by the host machine's OS.

Reliability: High

Cost: High

Pros:

- More isolated (HyperVisor + OS), making it harder to compromise the host machine in the event the virtual machine is hijacked. You can have as many as you manually allocate resources to.

Cons:

- They consume a set amount of resources from the Host machine while they are on, increasing cost
- They are a bit trickier to deploy and orchestrate due to the aforementioned

---

#### Containers

These emulate an OS, however these are run under processes directly in the host machine's OS and are built to be lightweight with a singular purpose.

Reliability: High

Cost: Medium

Pros:

- They can be started, stopped, frozen and overall controlled very easily with the use of orchestration, allowing for more optimal usage of resources in the host machine.
- They are very maleable, which means you can create a container for a specific type of operation you want and call upon it for any given task.
- Crazy fast deployment with the aforementioned, making it less painful to kill host machines when they aren't in use.

Cons:

- They have less isolation, which means vulnerabilities may compromise the host machine more easily in the event of invasion.

---

#### Serverless

This is a niche concept that, contrary to its name, still involves a server. However its way of deployment is its strength, focusing on tiny requests that are simple albeit numerous.

Reliability: Yes?

Cost: Very Low to Absurdly High

Pros:

- The idea behind it is executing a single tiny function that integrates with a system already in place. Clients send requests to a Gateway which then triggers the Serverless function, and they get a response.
- Singularly cheap requests that would otherwise take up a dedicated server to receive en masse and executed can be handled by Serverless.
- You pay by time used to execute these functions, which should execute super fast, so it scales very well.

Cons:

- Works in tandem with other things so it is not a silver bullet by any means.
- Poorly optimized functions or even poorly thought out requirements can quickly elevate cost.
- Limited Technology availability (provider dictates which technologies you may call upon in Serverless, anything else is a "jury-rig")

Comment: I see a lot of people state `This is a niche concept that, contrary to its name, still involves a server.`. Of course, this is true but why aren't people saying the same thing about wireless? This still involves wires, right? I think most people are missing the conceptual point of 'serverless'. With wireless you do not have to worry about wires any more, with serverless you do not have to worry about servers any more. This is the same level of abstraction. Serverless is not about functions: it is about stop worrying about servers. A database as a service is serverless as well.

Comment: @GuyT Well I've made this answer a community wiki so people may chime in on the points, terms and examples; if you have examples of swapping things with Serverless then you're also welcome to edit it in. I still think it's very easy to misconstrue what Serverless means so I've written that segment down.

Comment: @GuyT Also I don't get why you say it isn't about functions; I mean that's how you set it up and how they fundamentally charge you, no? Execution time of those lambda functions.

Comment: I don't think that thats `how you set it up`. Serverless is far broader than that. Serverless is a concept where you do not have to care about servers. It aren't just functions, but services like databases, application servers, service busses, etc.

Comment: @GuyT Right, well function as a service is still a big part of Serverless with it being the first thing most people I know think of when it is brought up; You're more than welcome to expand on Serverless (FaaS vs etc) categories for the answer otherwise it will just be me chiming in my interpretations. I opted to get no rep from this answer precisely so it can get help.